# Which browsers & databases supported by phonegap

Tags: database, browser, cordova

Which browsers are supported in phone gap & which databases  are supported by phone gap ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight from Phonegap website -

> PhoneGap is an HTML5 app platform that allows you to author native
>   applications with web technologies and get access to APIs and app
>   stores.

What this means is it is not browser dependent. The code compiles to native application. You don't need a browser to run it.

Comment: What databases are supported by phonegap

Comment: SQLite is supported by phonegap. It is used in all major mobile OS such as iOS, android, blackberry